# Huge Time Taken for Hive Query to execute

Tags: sql, hive

```
WITH Employee AS
  ( SELECT E.Com_Id,
           Com.Sinl_ID CLASS.Details_ID,
           Employee E
   INNER JOIN employee_Det Det ON E.Com_ID=Det.Com_ID
   INNER JOIN Employee_Sig Sig ON E.Com_ID=Sig.Main_Com_ID
   INNER JOIN Emp_Sig_Det Com Sig.Com_ID=Com.Com_ID
   INNER JOIN Employee_Class CLASS ON Com.F_ID=Class.Class_Id 
   ******N*******
   INNER JOIN Employee_AB_Class ABC ON E.Com_ID=AB.Main_Com_Id
   INNER JOIN Emp_AB_Class_Sig ABC_Sig ON AB.COM_ID=ABC_SIG.COM_ID
   INNER JOIN Employee_Class Class1 ABC_Sig.F_ID=Class1.Class_Id
   WHERE Det.ODate='2015-01-01'
     AND Sig.ODate='2015-01-01'
     AND Com.ODate='2015-01-01'
     AND Class.ODate='2015-01-01'
     AND Abc.ODate='2015-01-01'
     AND ABC_Sig.ODate='2015-01-01'
     AND Class.ODate='2015-01-01'
     AND ),
     DEPT AS
  ( SELECT E.Com_Id,
           Com.Sinl_ID CLASS.Details_ID,
           DEPT E
   INNER JOIN DEPT_Det Det ON E.Com_ID=Det.Com_ID
   INNER JOIN DEPT_Sig Sig ON E.Com_ID=Sig.Main_Com_ID
   INNER JOIN DEPT_Sig_Det Com Sig.Com_ID=Com.Com_ID
   INNER JOIN DEPT_Class CLASS ON Com.F_ID=Class.Class_Id 
   ******N*******
   INNER JOIN DEPT_AB_Class ABC ON E.Com_ID=AB.Main_Com_Id
   INNER JOIN DEPT_AB_Class_Sig ABC_Sig ON AB.COM_ID=ABC_SIG.COM_ID
   INNER JOIN DEPT_Class Class1 ABC_Sig.F_ID=Class1.Class_Id
   WHERE Det.ODate='2015-01-01'
     AND Sig.ODate='2015-01-01'
     AND Com.Date='2015-01-01'
     AND Class.ODate='2015-01-01'
     AND Abc.ODate='2015-01-01'
     AND ABC_Sig.ODate='2015-01-01'
     AND Class.ODate='2015-01-01'
     AND ),
SELECT *
FROM Employee
UNION ALL
SELECT *
FROM DEPT;
```

Counts of the following Tables are too huge to be processed in 
   Hive, Can you please, provide an hint how to increase the performance

**Employee Counts**

```
Det - 15 Million 
Sig - 15 Million
Com - 10 Million
Class - 10 Million
Abc.ODate - 1000 Records
ABC_Sig -10 Million
Class.ODate- 10 Million
```

**Dept Counts**

```
Det - 25 Million 
Sig - 25 Million
Com -20 Million
Class - 20 Million
Abc.ODate - 1000 Records
ABC_Sig -50 Million
Class -  50 Million
```

Comment: Count you have posted, is it for a single day (as mentioned in where condition) or for whole table. by Default `PPD` is set, if not try to set and see if it improves. Also try to post your `query plan`.

Comment: This is for a single day and also date is partition column

Comment: how about putting query plan and checking if ppd is set to true

Comment: What is ppd?  Thanks

Comment: put `explain` in front of your query run it and put the output here.  also run following `hive -e "set hive.optimize.ppd" and out the output here.